# How to append variables to already instantiated smarty array?

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I am using Prestashop 1.6 and am trying to append variables to an already instantiated smarty array. I have created a *.tpl file and I assigned some variables to the smarty array e.g:

```
public function hookExtraCarrier($params)
{
        //previous code is deleted.
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'wineo_free_shipping_id' => Configuration::get('WINEO_FREE_CARRIER_ID'),
            'this_path' => $this->_path,
            'this_path_ssl' => Tools::getShopDomainSsl(true, true).__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/'.$this->name.'/',
        ));

    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'wineocarrier.tpl');
}
```

I have another method that I want to add more variables to the array. I have tried things like:

```
public function addCarrierNameList()
{
    //previous code is deleted.
    if (isset($carrierNameNorm)) {
      $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'wineo_shipping_type' => $carrierNameNorm['name']
      ));
    }
    // echo '<pre>', print_r($carrierNameNorm['name']),'</pre>';
    // return $this->display(__FILE__, 'wineocarrier.tpl');

  }
}
```

I cannot get the 'wineo_shipping_type' variable in the template file.

What is the best way to approach this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you add a call to the `addCarrierNameList` function in your `hookExtraCarrier` function ?

Comment: @roberto06, no the second method is called by an ajax function and it updates the view.

Comment: And what's the point of updating smarty variable after the template was already rendered? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @TheDrot I want to show or hide a <section> based on a ajax call.

Comment: I solved it with JS. I show and hide the element. Did not succeed with smarty...

Comment: Not sure but try `$this->smarty->assign(..` if you are inside a module